# What's bad about gaining weight?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets, lucky-star

At around 4:40 in the 1st episode of *The Quintessential Quintuplets*, Uesugi said that eating too much would make Itsuki gain weight, and then Itsuki get pissed.

Isn't gaining weight as a teenage very normal? That's how your body develops. Why was Itsuki annoyed?

[image]

[image]

Another example about gaining weight is from *Lucky Start*. At around 9:30 in Episode 22, Konata said to Kagami, 'you will gain weight'. Then Kagami got sad.

[image]

What's so bad about gaining weight in Japan?

Comment: This isn't really an anime-oriented trope, or question.  It comes up in anime because it comes up in society as a body image issue.  Gaining weight may be undesirable for any number of social pressure reasons, but there are some subversions to this in some cases.  In the general, this is just typical teenager behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Well gain weight really just means get fat but...

Translation? In the manga Fuutarou says actually 'fat', not just weight. But eh that's just my manga's translation.

[image]

---

Let's see the Japanese...

[image]

It says '太るぞ (ふとるぞ)' and then Itsuki says 'ふとっ...' (I think it's the small っ not the large つ.)

---

P.S. I think Uesugi likes extra thicc girls, but I don't know if Fuutarou likes extra thicc girls.